# Setting up a LAN with load balanced internet

Tags: active-directory, load-balancing, windows-server-2012, internet

I have been looking and researching for the last week on this but haven't found anything conclusive which might apply to the situation that we are trying to solve.

I have a small start-up which now needs to have proper network structure so that we can expand rapidly. At the moment, I am the networking guy here :) since we have yet to hire one.

So here's the situation. Basically, at the moment, we are primarily a windows based org
with about 4 desktops, 1 server and about 2-5 laptops/devices. All  these are based on Microsoft Logins and direct access to 2 internet connections.

What I am trying to do is consolidate all this into a proper network that looks something this:

[image]

*Note: The main server has 3 NIC available

To achieve the above , here are the questions I have

1. How do I achieve Bandwidth Merging with of the two NIC and act as
   the DNS & DHCP server for the rest of the network ( Would NIC teaming apply? )
2. Is it possible to have a bare metal hypervisor and then have 2 separate os running. One as the Domain Controller + Firewall & other as a Win8 IIS & SQL Server.
3. Would it be better to have Windows Server 2012 install as the Host OS and have the Win8 act as a guest os?

FYI, I do plan on getting multiple server and separating the virtual servers but at a later stage.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes. 3) Yes.

Comment: Thanks for adding in the image. Could you elaborate on the answers please?

Comment: What hypervisor are you planning to use? Are you planning to move to some form of clustering in the future or simply multiple host systems?

Comment: Hyper V is what I was planning to use. Don't think we will be using clustering anytime soon, since this is a very small office network for now ( at least a year). Right now, the idea is to just host multiple system on the server since we have very good spec's on it ( 16GB ram expandable upto 64GB, I7 Gen 3 processor )

Comment: We do plan to move to dedicated servers as we see the need.i.e separating the AD , the Webserver & The Files servers hopefully in the next 4-5 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) How do I achieve Bandwidth Merging with of the two NIC and act as the DNS & DHCP server for the rest of the network ( Would NIC teaming apply? )

I would agree with mfinni on the multi-WAN router and to move the server from the in-line position. Not only would that help with security - allowing you to place everything behind a firewall - but also remove it from routing the traffic from the network.

> 2) Is it possible to have a bare metal hypervisor and then have 2 separate os running. One as the Domain Controller + Firewall & other as a Win8 IIS & SQL Server.

I would do a full OS install just for the ease of using the GUI but there is an argument to be made for a minimal host OS. From your spec's I don't think you will have a problem running the VM's you mentioned.

> 3) Would it be better to have Windows Server 2012 install as the Host OS and have the Win8 act as a guest os?

Can't say it better than HopelessN00b. 'Yes'.

I would also suggest that in the future you build two DCs. Depending on how critical they are & how difficult they would be to rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

You would be much better served to put some sort of dual-WAN router up front (there are plenty of them available on the market today), instead of putting a server there. Especially if the server is also going to contain your internal resources that should be secured, like your AD.

You can still use your DC VM guest as the DHCP and DNS server for the LAN clients; in fact, it's a good idea to definitely make it the DNS server. DHCP, less important to be on the same box, but it's your call.